# Egit / Github - Get files from partner

Tags: java, android, eclipse, github, egit

This may be a stupid question, but after several times trying to get this right I'm getting frustrated. I want to use github to host my project, we are 2 people working on the project and the aim was to share the work. And help each other.

I managed to create the resepetory, and committing to master branch. If the other guy deletes the whole project he gets the latest updates, but I'm sure this is not the way its supposed to work.

Lets say I commmit a new class file. I commit this file, how could the other person download this file? We've tried pull, synchronize etc etc without any luck. The only way we have found to give him "my" latest updates is for him to delete all content and make the project from scratch.

What am I missing? How can we synchronize workspaces? So I can see and download his changes when i open Eclipse? (We are not working in the same class). So really all I want to do is download he's latest commits.

EDIT : My solution was that my partner was working in a copy of the local git workspace. So instead of modifying the local repo he was modifying a copy of it inside the Eclipse workspace. And because of this nothing updated when he did the pull. I also switched from Egit to GitHub command line tool, and I'm in love. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally with GitHub, all of what you have described works perfectly, I have not had any kind of similar problems.

One thing about git, a commit is a bit different than a commit in SVN. With git, you use `push` and `pull` to interact with your remote repository.

I am not sure what you mean when you say:

> If the other guy deletes the whole project he gets the latest updates,
>   but I'm sure this is not the way its supposed to work.

That being said, I have never used Egit, I prefer to stick to the command line for all my git needs. I have had issues with other software (Sublime Text 2) where I would have to exit the editor, then run all my commits and other git actions. I do not know how well Eclipse plays with git in general.

Try to have your partner run `git remote -v` just to make sure he is tracking the repo properly.  Also, do you know if he set up an SSH key for GitHub, or you sending your pushes and pulls via https?

Keep in mind this is pretty hard thing to help you out with since I am not sitting at your computer. [GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/) has some very good walkthroughs on setting up git and remote repositories.

Also, I highly recommend the time to go through [CodeSchool](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-git) intro to git. If this is your first time using Git, this is the best starting point.

Comment: Thanks, what I meant with deleting was since the pull-request doesn't fetch anything. (Local branch up to date) even tough I just committed a whole set of changes to the remote repository, he's git is claiming that everything is up to date. He needs to delete everything and fetch from Create New Project. When this is done he gets the new files. I'v read many many pages on how it's supposed to work. But it just does not! Thanks for the answer anyway, Il read trough again to check if i missed something. I understand that help over the internet is hard/limited on this issue.

Comment: @iNzzane Is this your first time using Git?

Comment: @iNzzane Has he tried [cloning](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository) the project instead creating a new one from the Eclipse menu. Recommend doing so the from the command line, I find it much more reliable, and with better error reporting.

Comment: Yeah, hes cloning it. Nor from the command line tough. Yes, this is our first time using git. I think mine work ok, since I'm able to se my commits updating online. Bu he's having problems, at the moment a "fast-forward" error is preventing him to commit and push.. a google search suggested to pull before he committed. But then it just says "everything is up to date" and "Result failed". But everything is not up-to date. Because I have pushed 3 classes, and I can see them in the remote resp.

Comment: @iNzzane Is it a private repository? When I visit the link you posted below, I only see your 'try_git' repo and 'Timelonn.' 'Timelonn' gives me a message "Nothing to see here yet."

Comment: I just wiped it clean. So that could be the cause. But yes, its private.

Comment: @iNzzane "Timelonn" is private? Or the project you are talking about is private. "Timelonn" is not if I can see it. Either way, has your partner been given the proper read/write access? Since you have just wiped it clean, I would recommend following the steps [here](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) in getting yourself set up again.

Comment: Yep, followed it. Now using the command line i created and uploaded my code to the repository. Downloaded it on my partners pc. All good so far. I then used "git add ." to add all files, then i changed a comment in a class. Wrote "git status" but it dont detect that the file is changed?

Comment: @iNzzane Where is the change not being detected?

Comment: Finally I got it! :) I meant that Git did not detect that the file was modified and that it was ready for commit. The error was that I "copied" the local repo into Eclipse workspace, and then edited it. So no changes was made to the github local repo. I now linked Eclipse into the github working directory. And everything workes perfect. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

There are much more complicated scenarios, but basically, you need to "push" your commits to the upstream, and pull your colleague's.

Clone the repo.  By cloning it you will guarantee that it has an "origin", the github remote.  You make changes in your local repo, committing them as you go.  When you are at a milestone, use Team > Push to push all of your commits to github.  Your colleague will pull them, as described below.

When you try to push, you may discover that your colleague has pushed changes and that git will not allow you to push until you merge.  Try Team > Pull which will merge the remote changes into your local repo.  If there are no conflicts, you can now push.  If there are conflicts, fix them and then commit.  Then push.

This is a substantial simplification but may get you started.  The main point is that the equivalent of a SVN commit is, in git, two, maybe three, operations: add, commit, push.  Git pull is vaguely analogous to SVN checkout.

Take a day to read up on git.  There's great documentation at GitHub.  Once you get the hang of it, you'll love it.

Comment: I'm sure the tool is fantastic. I'v used some hours to read, and I do think i understand the basics. But still errors all the way. Just want to see one single function working! Haha, on the more serious side i may have to take some more time reading. Something must be wrong, I just don't know what yet.

But I suppose it's something like this? 
1. Create repo. 
2. Commit first changes and push.
3. Partner clones repo.
4. Partner does some changes and commit and push.
5. I pull..
6. I'm happy.

Right? But I'm not happy.. yet!

Comment: The scenario you describe should work.  Verify that the push in step 2 worked, by looking at github.  In step 6 you might have to merge, but otherwise, you should be good.  Are you seeing a error message?  What does it say?

Answer (score 1):

When using git to collaborate on a project, you are managing both a local and remote repository. When you *commit*, you are only saving changes to your local repository. After committing, you need to do a *push* in order for your changes to be saved to your remote repository. After doing that, if your collaborator does a *pull* he will get your changes.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Commit and push. The changes is made to the remote repository. Because if I delete and add my project I still get all the files. Even so he has to delete the project every time I do a edit on a file. I'm sure we're doing something wrong. I just dont know what.

Comment: @iNzzane Start simple, when you `push` to GitHub, do you get a message indicating success or failure? When your partner runs `git pull`, what message is dispayed for him?

Comment: When i push to remote..the repository updates(on github). And egit claims it was successful. My partner then tries the pull, but then he's egit claims he's local repository is in sync with the remote. (Witch its clearly is not).

Comment: @iNzzane and when both you and your partner perform _git remote -v_, you get matching results for your repository location?

Comment: Matching result yes. In the format : 
https://github.com/iNzzane/projectname.git (fetch)
and the same for pull.